How do I create a finished application using only Racket, Figma + something like Android Studio
It sounds like a challenge and I am not sure if there is any way to do it. Basically, I have to create a simple app for sports teams and fans. They should be able to create an account/log in, look for different events that are going on, like them, etc. I am not allowed to use any other language except Racket, and I can use Figma for the design prototypes + Android studio/anything else to put it together. I know how to use both of them separately, but not really professionally (but I have time to learn). The main question is: is it possible? Or will I require another language anyway?
I created databases/hash-tables in Racket to store data + functions. Made a prototype in Figma. Now I am at the point when I can either stop and get good marks or go deeper and try to make something finished out of it and get excellent marks if this works out. But I don't know where to look and how to connect those parts together and make it work. Any advice would be highly appreciated!!
